# How to work with a very large "allowed_domains" attribute in scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

The following is my scrapy code:

```
def get_host_regex(self, spider):
    """Override this method to implement a different offsite policy"""
    allowed_domains = getattr(spider, 'allowed_domains', None)
    if not allowed_domains:
        return re.compile('') # allow all by default
    regex = r'^(.*\.)?(%s)$' % '|'.join(re.escape(d) for d in allowed_domains if d is not None)
    return re.compile(regex)

def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.host_regex = self.get_host_regex(spider)
        self.domains_seen = set()
```

Because the allowed_domains is very big, it throws this exception:

> regex = r'^(.*.)?(%s)$' % '|'.join(re.escape(d) for d in allowed_domains if d is not None)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What exception are you getting? How long is the domain list?

Comment: fllow exception:OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded and from the source code i know 'regex = r'^(.*.)?(%s)$' % '|'.join(re.escape(d) for d in allowed_domains if d is not None)' cause the issue.    i have fifty thousand domains

Comment: do you really need to limit requests to these 50'000 domains only, and not anything outside this list? Otherwise you might be better off not defining `allow_domains`, this will allow any domain.

Comment: I need crawl website page  and the crawl deep limit is 2 .either i need limit crawl domain, so I must define allowed_domains and not empty. but it is occur exception just the allowed_domains is very long. so i don`t know any question to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own `OffsiteMiddleware` variation, with a different implementation checking requests to domains not in the spider's `allowed_domains`.

For example, add this in a `middlewares.py` file,

```
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite import OffsiteMiddleware
from scrapy.utils.httpobj import urlparse_cached


class SimpleOffsiteMiddleware(OffsiteMiddleware):

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        # don't build a regex, just use the list as-is
        self.allowed_hosts = getattr(spider, 'allowed_domains', [])
        self.domains_seen = set()

    def should_follow(self, request, spider):
        if self.allowed_hosts:
            host = urlparse_cached(request).hostname or ''
            # does 'www.example.com' end with 'example.com'?
            # test this for all allowed domains
            return any([host.endswith(h) for h in self.allowed_hosts])
        else:
            return True
```

and change your settings to disable the default OffsiteMiddleware, and add yours:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': None,
    'myproject.middlewares.SimpleOffsiteMiddleware': 500,
}
```

Warning: this middleware is not tested. This is a very naive implementation, definitely not very efficient (testing string inclusion for each of 50'000 possible domains for each and every request).
You could use another backend to store the list and test a hostname value, like sqlite for example.

Comment: What's mean of 'host_list',  when i run you implements offsitemiddle ,  give fllowing error, 'SimpleOffsiteMiddleware' object has no attribute 'host_list'

Comment: sorry, code was not tested, it should be `allowed_hosts`

Comment: it work well, but i want to know if it will filter out does not belong to allowed_domains? in addadition, the efficient is very well? think you .

Comment: the change is not very efficient , fllowing craw rate:
2016-04-07 18:17:40 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 100 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 98 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-07 18:18:40 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 100 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 98 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-07 18:19:40 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 100 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 98 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-07 18:20:52 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 120 pages (at 20 pages/min), scraped 106 items (at 8 items/min)  do you have any change?