# How to increase memory available to re2 regex engine?

Tags: python, re2

I am use this github project, https://github.com/axiak/pyre2/

re2.compile has max_mem argument, but i dont't know how to increase memory available to re2 regex enginee, Are you any suggestions?

Comment: What's your exact problem here? What happens when you provide a value higher than the default for that argument? The default value is about 8 megabyte.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440681/how-to-work-with-a-very-large-allowed-domains-attribute-in-scrapy/36454033?noredirect=1#comment60558227_36454033 . for this question , i use pyre2 replace the re of scrapy. because my domain is very big.but when i used re2, it throws memory exception, the scrapy author tell me increase memory for re2 enginee, but i don't know hot to increase?

Comment: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1908   the github of scrapy  issue, how to increase default value?

Comment: Just give a higher value than the default one as `max_mem` argument.

Comment: can you give a example?, because I don't know how in the document for max_mem use, think you